# Unicorn method missing generated_attribute_methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, unicorn, newrelic

I have a application that uses `rails + unicorn + nginx` and `capistrano` for deployment.

It was all working fine, until yesterday when i ran a bundle update. suddenly the unicorn server cant start because of a missing method: `generated_attribute_methods`

In development i can start and use the server just fine, but in production it gives me this error

this is the output from server start from my machine that uses rvm (production):

```
I, [2013-05-14T10:05:59.070825 #52560]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
/Users/nicoskaralis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:55:in `method_missing': undefined local variable or method `generated_attribute_methods' for #<Class:0x007fe254b1fe98> (NameError)
    from /Users/nicoskaralis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/base.rb:405:in `initialize_generated_modules'
    from /Users/nicoskaralis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/base.rb:397:in `inherited'
    from /Users/nicoskaralis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/session_store.rb:79:in `<class:SessionStore>'
    from /Users/nicoskaralis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/session_store.rb:53:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
    from /Users/nicoskaralis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/session_store.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/nicoskaralis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:138:in `session_store'
    from /Users/nicoskaralis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:273:in `block in default_middleware_stack'
    from /Users/nicoskaralis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:237:in `tap'
    from /Users/nicoskaralis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:237:in `default_middleware_stack'
    from /Users/nicoskaralis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `app'
    from /Users/nicoskaralis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:31:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /Users/nicoskaralis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/nicoskaralis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/nicoskaralis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/nicoskaralis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /Users/nicoskaralis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/nicoskaralis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/nicoskaralis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/nicoskaralis/Documents/WayTaxi/webapp/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from config.ru:4:in `require'
    from config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/nicoskaralis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/nicoskaralis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from config.ru:1:in `new'
    from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
    from /Users/nicoskaralis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn.rb:44:in `eval'
    from /Users/nicoskaralis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn.rb:44:in `block in builder'
    from /Users/nicoskaralis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:722:in `call'
    from /Users/nicoskaralis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:722:in `build_app!'
    from /Users/nicoskaralis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:140:in `start'
    from /Users/nicoskaralis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/nicoskaralis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/unicorn:19:in `load'
    from /Users/nicoskaralis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/unicorn:19:in `<main>'
    from /Users/nicoskaralis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
    from /Users/nicoskaralis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

this is the output from server start from my server, using rbenv (production):

```
I, [2013-05-14T10:14:14.599183 #25840]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
/home/deployer/rails_apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:55:in `method_missing': undefined local variable or method `generated_attribute_methods' for #<Class:0x0000000204fe50> (NameError)
    from /home/deployer/rails_apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/base.rb:405:in `initialize_generated_modules'
    from /home/deployer/rails_apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/base.rb:397:in `inherited'
    from /home/deployer/rails_apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/session_store.rb:79:in `<class:SessionStore>'
    from /home/deployer/rails_apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/session_store.rb:53:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
    from /home/deployer/rails_apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/session_store.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/deployer/rails_apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:138:in `session_store'
    from /home/deployer/rails_apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:273:in `block in default_middleware_stack'
    from /home/deployer/rails_apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:237:in `tap'
    from /home/deployer/rails_apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:237:in `default_middleware_stack'
    from /home/deployer/rails_apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `app'
    from /home/deployer/rails_apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:31:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /home/deployer/rails_apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/deployer/rails_apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /home/deployer/rails_apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /home/deployer/rails_apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /home/deployer/rails_apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /home/deployer/rails_apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /home/deployer/rails_apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /home/deployer/rails_apps/webapp/releases/20130514130605/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from config.ru:4:in `require'
    from config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
    from /home/deployer/rails_apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/deployer/rails_apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from config.ru:1:in `new'
    from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
    from /home/deployer/rails_apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn.rb:44:in `eval'
    from /home/deployer/rails_apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn.rb:44:in `block in builder'
    from /home/deployer/rails_apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:722:in `call'
    from /home/deployer/rails_apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:722:in `build_app!'
    from /home/deployer/rails_apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:140:in `start'
    from /home/deployer/rails_apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/deployer/rails_apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
    from /home/deployer/rails_apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
```

which is odd because i've set in capistrano to use ruby 1.9.3-p392, but since is ubuntu and it was working i dont see how this could be the problem

what is wrong here? what should i do?

**EDIT**

as required the `config.ru`

```
# This file is used by Rack-based servers to start the application.

require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)
run Webapp::Application
```

**EDIT 2**

The command i'm using to start the server is basically this:

```
bundle exec unicorn -p 3000 -c ./config/unicorn.rb -E production
```

and if i change to

```
bundle exec unicorn_rails -l 0.0.0.0:3000 -E production
```

it works, but i dont put my configuration inside the server, and besides, i read that the `unicorn_rails` shouldn't be used anymore

**EDIT 3**

Apparently my problem is inside `Webapp::Application.initialize!`

```
puts "before" # => prints
Webapp::Application.initialize!
puts "after" # => don't prints
```

**EDIT 4 15/05**

I was testing in other machines and in my server (ubuntu 10.04) and on my machine (mac os x) it doesnt start the server, giving that error. But on my coworker machine (ubuntu 12.04) it works fine.

And after some tests i decided to clean my development code and download the latest version from git. now sometimes it works fine, sometimes it gives the error.

What could it be?

**EDIT 5**

Apparently this is because of new relic + unicorn, commenting this lines:

```
if defined? Unicorn
  ::NewRelic::Agent.manual_start()
  ::NewRelic::Agent.after_fork(:force_reconnect => true)
end
```

make everything work normally

Comment: Are you using a database to store sessions in production mode?

Comment: yes, using this: ``Webapp::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store``

Comment: does it have some thing to do with the server not starting?

Comment: And did you run the required migration? `rails generate session_migration`?

Comment: yes, and also capistrano runs the migration for me on the server.

Comment: Okay, can you post the config.ru file?

Comment: i never changed the config.ru, but here it is